# USB > USB (PC > PC) direct connection Windows XP

Tags: usb, home-networking, netbook

From [this thread](https://superuser.com/questions/324724/how-can-i-connect-two-laptops-with-a-usb-network-link-bridge), Windows Easy Transfer is a solution to connect two Windows computers over USB to USB, but this software only transfers user settings, documents, and application, all in one step.  It is used to migrate a user from one PC to another.

I need a netbook to access the DVD drive of a laptop.  The netbook does not have an optical drive.

Is this impossible over a USB-USB cable?

Is it impossible to use USB in the same way ethernet it is used for networking?  Why is a USB-USB connection different for computer-computer versus computer to specific devices like printers/scanners etc?  A computer is simply not detected as a device, while printers are.

**Update:** I'm aware I can use a cross-over ethernet cable; I simply don't have one.  I will try a normal cable though, at the suggestion below that Windows might detect and update the direct connection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a read on [this article](http://www.hardwaresecrets.com/article/Connecting-Two-PCs-Using-a-USB-USB-Cable/248/2), it does explain allot to things involved with USB to USB networking and an give you insight to what you need to buy.

- [This software.](http://www.virtualserialport.com/products/usb-over-network/) lets you use USB ports over an existing Network. But that is also something else again.

I do however suggest using a cross over cable to connect your two pc's

<strike>[A guide here](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-GB/windows-vista/Connect-two-computers-using-a-crossover-cable)</strike>

[Another proper guide here](http://www.herongyang.com/Windows/Crossover-Cable-Network-Configuration.html)

> One thing to rememeber with this type of network, using computer names
>   will not work (it could- but most likely not) So when mapping drives
>   use the IP Adress not NetBiOS name, 
>   the same when browsing. `\\192.168.0.1` in explorer bar (not IE)

*You can also use `ipconfig /all` for more verbose detials of the network settings*

[image]

I would strongly suggest not trying to use USB to USB, because on BIOS based computers do not support this natively.

*For example. Using a macintosh, during boot you can use a fire wire cable to connect 2 macs and they can use each other resources without any problem by a press of a button, usually "T" on boot.*

USB to USB is a bit like  [Sisyphus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sisyphus)

[image]

Comment: Most PCs and network devices now a days do detect themselves that they are in a "cross over situation" and resolve this by software. You should be fine with a normal network cable.

Comment: Yes, you should be fine.. but if you want to be sure. Use a cross over

Comment: If one of the systems is gig e it should do autonegotiation

Comment: @BetaRide: AFAIR the auto-crossing feature in mandatory for all Gigabit Ethernet ports. This the reason why most devices support it.

Comment: I tried a normal ethernet cable, and switched TCP/IP to automatic settings for both PCs.  Their IP addresses became 169.254.54.201 & 169.254.155.14, with 255.255.0.0 subnet mask, but they couldn't ping each other.  Does it matter what IP address and subnet mask they have?

Comment: Sorry that guide before was rubbish. go figure..i update my anser and added some hints.

Comment: @ppumkin: thanks; I never knew there was a bridge USB-USB cable.

Comment: @ppumkin: the guide to cross over cabling has no mention of what gateway and DNS entries to use, unfortunately, but using the PC's own IP as gateway and DNS server works.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: I now just need to work out how to set up network profiles, so I don't have to manually set TCP/IP settings each time I replace the LAN cable with the direct ethernet cable connecting to the netbook.

Comment: Instead of doing that. Get a router that has a DHCP server. Connect both computer to it and use the Automatic settings. If you use internet and have a router.. it already has all this functionality.. so buy a switch, plug one cable into the Routers LAN port(if it has only 1) then plug all your other computers into the Switch, and the DNS names will work, internet and all auto.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a special reason why you don't want to use a network cable? If both devices on the same WLAN you don't even need a cable.

You can share the DVD drive via the context menu on your laptop and access it as a network drive on your netbook. (Make sure both devices do use the same workgroup name.)

Comment: The special reason is I simply don't have an ethernet cross over cable, and a straight ethernet cable hasn't worked, although I may have set TCP/IP settings incorrectly for that.  I can't ping either PC from the other over wireless; see this thread: http://superuser.com/questions/271343/cant-ping-workgroup-pc-over-wireless-wep

Comment: Then you should resolve this problem. The USB cable soltion is not likely to make you happy.

Answer (score 0):

I found a resource on the web, you can achieve two PC's CD-ROM drive sharing using a USB data link cable, see:[Reference1](http://www.cnblogs.com/LiuKaiFa/p/USB_data_link_cable_API.html), [Reference2](http://blog.csdn.net/zzkjliu/article/details/12838383)

Comment: Can you summarize the information in your answer in case the links go dead?